# Remove prefixes from filenames

Tags: solaris, rename, filenames

I have a bunch of files as follows:

```
04602635_b0294.DAT20120807164534
04602637_b0297.DAT20120807164713
04602638_b0296.DAT20120807164637
04602639_b0299.DAT20120807164819
04602640_b0298.DAT20120807164748
04602641_b0300.DAT20120807164849
04602650_b0301.DAT20120807164921
04602652_b0302.DAT20120807164956
```

I need to rename them to exclude the prefix. It needs to look like this..

```
b0294.DAT20120807164534
b0297.DAT20120807164713
b0296.DAT20120807164637
b0299.DAT20120807164819
b0298.DAT20120807164748
b0300.DAT20120807164849
b0301.DAT20120807164921
b0302.DAT20120807164956
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to add that I am using Solaris.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
for file in * ; do
    echo mv -v "$file" "${file#*_}"
done
```

run this to satisfy that everything is ok. 
if it is, remove `echo` from command and it will rename files as you want.

```
"${file#*_}"
```

is a usual substitution feature in the shell. It removes all chars before the first `_` symbol (including the symbol itself). For more details look [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02).

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly is happening in `"${file#*_}"`?

Comment: I added explanation to my answer.

Comment: IMO, most all scripts should be written to echo the desired command output.  But don't then remove the `echo`, just pipe the script output into `bash`.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the tool [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574) for this:

```
rename "s/.*_//" *
```

If you append `-n` it won't rename anything and just show you what would have been done without `-n`.

In response to rush's comment: my `rename` is is actually a link to `prename` shipped with Debian's and Ubuntu's `perl` package.

Comment: Note, that `rename` not always is the same on different systems and sometimes its syntax may differ.

Comment: The asker has now added that he's using Solaris. So this rename command (which is specific to Debian and derivatives) is not available to him.

Comment: ...unless he manages to build it from source.

Comment: @Gilles `perl-rename` is not at all specific to Debian. It's just not called `rename` but `perl-rename` or `prename` in other distributions. It should always be in the repos though and [one is installed with perl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/22222) as well.

Comment: @terdon *A command to rename files whose basic usage is a perl expression* is not specific to Debian. Such a command, *called `rename` and likely to be installed without explicitly requesting a package which is not called just `rename`*, is specific to Debian. Other Linux distributions call the command `prename` or `perl-rename` to avoid confusion with the util-linux `rename` and don't bundle it with the perl package, and I'm not aware of any non-Linux unix that ships it under the name `rename` or that ships it in a default installation under any name.