# How can I strip out a numeric prefix from multiple filenames?

Tags: rename, mv

I have >2000 files which are named like

```
123-FILENAME_TEXT_M101K_20150929.CSV
```

where `123` can be any three or four-digit number. The files are all within the same directory. I would like a script that removes the prefixing number and the dash. (i.e. the leading `123-` should be removed from the example name)

I have tried `mv **-FILENAME* FILENAME*`.
`rename` is not an available function

Comment: This question is very similar to [Remove prefixes from filenames](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45212). Maybe even a duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this, it will remove everything before the first `-`

```
for file in *-*.CSV
do
   newName="${file#*-}"
   mv -- "${file}" "${newName}"
done
```

Comment: The assignment is actually [one of the few places](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373) that don't need the quotes (unless you use an unquoted `$*` there in Bash; It's had a bunch of bugs with that)

Comment: Quotes are indeed a source of bug, but I didn't know that it was not needed on assignment. Tx

Comment: Quotes won't harm anyway. To clarify @ilkkachu's comment, in the case of bash's `var=$*`, it's the absence of quotes that cause problems.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit stuck, I have tried running this as a shell script but getting bad substitution - any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Solved, I was running as a .sh rather than .bash, even thou in my script I had #!/bin/bash.  Any all work now tysm

Answer (score 2):

I have tried by using combination of sed,awk and find . Tested and working fine

```
find . -type f -iname "*.CSV"| sed "s/^\.\///g"| sed -n '/^[0-9]\{4\}/p' | awk   -F "-" '{print "mv" " " $0 " " $2}'| sh
```