# How to remove a particular part of the filename for multiple filenames in macOS

Tags: osx

I have these files in a directory.

```
Mabel-A10_GTAGAGGA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Mabel-A5_GGACTCCT_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Mabel-A11_GCTCATGA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Mabel-A6_TAGGCATG_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

I want the output to look like this.

```
Mabel-A10_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Mabel-A5_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Mabel-A11_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Mabel-A6_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

Comment: You may also wish to look in apple.stackexchange.com - but please only post here _or_ there. The answer to your question is in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45212/remove-prefixes-from-filenames

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like to rename them:

```
for i in *
do
o=$(echo $i|awk -F_ '{print $1,$3,$4,$5}')
mv "$i" "$o"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will output shell commands that perform a series of 'mv' commands to accomplish your task:

```
for FILE in *.fastq.gz
do
    L="${FILE%%_*}_"
    R="${FILE#${L}*_}";
    printf 'mv -vi "%s" "%s"\n' "$FILE" "$L$R"
done
```

Run that once, and examine the output.  If there are lots of files, you may want to use `less` to review the commands.

If everything looks good, run the command again and pipe the output to `bash`.

It works by setting the variable L to everything left of the first underscore in the filename, plus the underscore itself.  It then forms a string R by stripping the string in L from the front of the filename, and stripping further to the next underscore.

```
mv -vi "Mabel-A10_GTAGAGGA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz" "Mabel-A10_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz"
mv -vi "Mabel-A11_GCTCATGA_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz" "Mabel-A11_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz"
mv -vi "Mabel-A5_GGACTCCT_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz" "Mabel-A5_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz"
mv -vi "Mabel-A6_TAGGCATG_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz" "Mabel-A6_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz"
```